# why is the text in the h1 wrapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a simple website and cant figure out my the h1 title is wrapping, the nav doesnt touch it and nothing seems to be interfering with it, causing it to wrap. I have declared white-space: nowrap; but its still wrapping, does anyone know what is causing this and how I can fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/xsqk3xk4/1/

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px){
    header{
        height: 120px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    header h1{
        margin: 0 0 0 8%;
        font-size: 2em;
        align-self: flex-start;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    header nav{
        display: block;
        align-self: flex-end;
    }
    nav ul{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        margin: 0 8% 0 0;
    }
    nav li{
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 4px 1%;
    }
    footer nav{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: your H1 isn't wrapping, add more text to it and you'll see it doesn't create a new line. ugh wait, what is your definition of "wrapping" ? i believe it is different than what it really is

Comment: the no-wrap is only effective on screen sizes larger than `min-width: 400px` again, i see no fault in the way it works now, am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine for me in the fiddle. Anyways if you remove the margin of the header `h1` then it appears properly.

```
header h1{
  margin:0;
...
}
```